# IdentityServer4 - ASP .Net core 2 - getting unauthorized even using a valid token

Tags: asp.net, token, identityserver4, unauthorized

I am accessing to my secure API (secured by identityServer4) from a .Net core mvc application.

When I login with a **registred user** i get a **valid token** from token endpoint of IdentityServer **BUT** when i go to access to API ressource using that token I got 401 response **unauthorized**, even it's new token and the only restriction to that API ressource is the role X and the user have already that role X.

Do you have please any idea why this is happening?

UPDATE:
Identity server is deployed on two web servers under a **load balancer**. when using the 
Does it have a relation that tokens are stored on In-Mermory of server?

Thank you.

Comment: Is anything logged to indicate why it might be being rejected?

Comment: It might help if you see the output window on Visual Studio and see for more details if present.

Comment: What are parameters are used to validate the Token?

If Roles are not matching then StatusCode should be 403

Answer (score 1):

My answer would look like kind of guessing because you don't provide much details.

Since you mentioned the load balancer, make sure that your IdentityServer4 app in both webservers is using the same data protection key.

you should read more about:
services.AddDataProtection()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Before you read you can check if this is really the problem or not by simply decoupling or shutting down one of the two web servers and keep only one. then try to refresh the token again and call the api.

This is just a quick answer about a common problem that developers face when they don't take scale out to many (web servers) in their consideration.

otherwise, please mention more details so I can help more :)

Answer (score 0):

Whene using a load balancer we should not use InMemory storage. 
The solution for this was to change the way we storing tokens and grants from InMemory storage to database storage.
see the tuto here https://deblokt.com/2019/09/20/02-identityserver4-entityframework/
and here http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html